# How to start at a specific step in a script?

Tags: python

I have a python script that executes 10 functions that follow each other and i want to make it possible for the users to start the execution of the script at a specific function.

For example :

> python main.py --start=function4

and the script only executes function4 and the next functions in the process.

I use getopt.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Try googling first, this is fairly basic and a tutorial might do you better.

Comment: I tried and i knew all the answers given to this question, but i was looking for a more "sexy" way to do it. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do e.g.

```
if start >= 1:
    function1()
if start >= 2:
    function2()
if start >= 3:
    function3()
```

or have a list of functions:

```
f = [None, function1, function2, function3, ...]
for f in f_list[start:]:
    f()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using ,

```
if __name__=='__main__':
     call_desiredfunction()
```

Example ,

```
def c():
    print 'c'

def b():
    print 'b'
    c()

def a():
    print 'a'
    b()


if __name__=='__main__':
    print 'Stared Execution'
    a()
```

Output:

```
Stared Execution
a
b
c
```

Answer (score 0):

Today I am allowed to advice you:

## Use goto

http://entrian.com/goto/

install the package:

```
$ pip install http://entrian.com/goto/goto-1.0.tar.gz#goto
```

write some code:

```
from goto import goto, label

label .getinput
i = raw_input("Enter either 'a', 'b' or 'c', or any other letter to quit: ")
if i in ('a', 'b', 'c'):
    goto *i
else:
    goto .quit

label .a
print "You typed 'a'"

label .b
print "You typed 'b'"

label .c
print "You typed 'c'"

label .quit
print "Finished\n"
```

and run it:

```
$ python gt.py 
Enter either 'a', 'b' or 'c', or any other letter to quit: b
You typed 'b'
You typed 'c'
Finished
```

Warning: look to your calendar before you use it in practice. Btw. the code really works.